# Can't deploy ConsenSys MultiSig wallet using Mist

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mist, contract-deployment, multisignature

I'm trying to deploy the MultiSig wallet provided by ConsenSys [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet/master/contracts/solidity/MultiSigWallet.sol) using Mist 0.8.10.

No matter how much I'm willing to pay in fees, it doesn't work. The contract compiles fine but when I press deploy I can see the following warnings:

- It seems this transaction will fail. If you submit it, it may consume
  all the gas you provide.
- The contract won't allow this transaction to be executed

If I click 'Send transaction' it fails every time with 'intrinsic gas too low'.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, though Mist is terribly bad at communicating what.

How can I find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Mist itself can only deploy simple contracts that don't depend on others. If there is another way to do it, I haven't found it.

However, one can open Remix from Develop -> Open Remix IDE which makes it very easy to deploy complex contracts.